# Using es6 spread to concat multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

We all know you can do:

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3];
let arr2 = [3,4,5];
let arr3 = [...arr1, ...arr2]; // [1,2,3,3,4,5]
```

But how do you make this dynamic to concat N arrays?

Comment: you could store the dynamic arrays in an array ...

Comment: or an object with arrays as values. Impossible to iterate unknown qty of individual variables

Comment: Why do you have to use the spread operator? The `concat` method still works...

Comment: Does Array.prototype.concat not do it for you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: Uh, ohh so ES5ify `Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.concat)` :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

One option is to use `reduce`:

```
let arrs = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]];
arrs.reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);
```

Of course, this is a slow solution (quadratic time). Alternatively, if you can use Lodash, `_.flatten` does exactly what you want, and does it more efficiently (linear time).

**EDIT**

Or, adapted from Xotic750's comment below,

```
[].concat(...arrs);
```

Which should be efficient (linear time).

Comment: One you have your arrays in an array, you could then. `Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arr)` Though this isn't using the spread operator any more.

Comment: @Xotic750 Nice, but you can do that using the spread operator! See my edit.

Comment: Note that in typescript you need to force the empty array to be typed if you want the return value to be `number[]` and not `any[]` (eg. `([] as number[]).concat(...arrs)`)

Comment: Are there any new other solutions for this?

Answer (score 22):

Another option could be:

```js
const nArrays = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9],
  [10, 11]
];
const flattened = [].concat(...nArrays);
console.log(flattened)
```

Comment: As of ES2019, you can just use `nArrays.flat()`

Answer (score 17):

```js
let fruits = ["apples", "bananas", "pears"];
let vegetables = ["corn", "potatoes", "carrots"];

let produce = [...fruits, ...vegetables];


console.log(produce);
```

Comment: This given code is exactly same as the given question. It is not an answer for making dynamiclly concat solution for N arrays.

Answer (score 4):

Best option is to use FlatMap, which helps us to conact multiple arrays into one single array.

Example:

```
let arrs = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]];
arrs.flatMap(a => a);
```

result will be

```
> (6) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 3):

Following solution works for me (spread operator in ES6):

```js
let array = ['my','solution','works'];
let newArray = [];
let newArray2 = [];
newArray.push(...array); //adding to same array
newArray2.push([...array]); //adding as child/leaf/sub-array
console.log(newArray);
console.log(newArray2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with spread syntax alone, as spread syntax requires you to know how many arrays you are concatenating in advance. However, you could write the following function:

```
function concatN(...arguments) {
    let accumulator = [];
    for(let arg = 0; arg < arguments.length; arg = arg + 1) {
        accumulator = [...accumulator, ...arguments[arg]];
    }
    return accumulator;
}
```

It probably won't be very efficient, though (repeated use of spread syntax is O(n²)). Using `Array.prototype.concat`would be better. You can just do:

```
[].concat(all, of, your, arrays);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use spread element within `for..of` loop to concatenate array values to a single array

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,3];
let arr2 = [3,4,5];
let arr3 = [];

for (let arr of [arr1, arr2 /* , arrN */]) arr3.push(...arr);

console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive function and `Array.prototype.concat`

```js
const concatN = (x,...xs) =>
  x === undefined ? [] : x.concat(concatN(...xs))

console.log(concatN([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]))
// [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

You can do the same thing using `reduce` and `Array.prototype.concat`. This is *similar* to the accepted answer but doesn't senselessly use spread syntax where `x.concat(y)` is perfectly acceptable (and likely heaps faster) in this case

```js
const concatN = (...xs) =>
  xs.reduce((x,y) => x.concat(y), [])

console.log(concatN([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]))
// [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can resolve using es6 following way

```
function mergeTwo(arr1, arr2) {
  let result = [...arr1, ...arr2];
  return result.sort((a,b) => a-b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,3];
let arr2 = [3,4,5];
let arrs = [arr1, arr2].flat(); // [1,2,3,3,4,5]

console.log(arrs);
```