# How can we merge more then two array of object into one array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

How can I merge more than two array of objects into one array of objects.
Like I have:

```
var arr1 = [{"userID": 554,"name":"abc"},{"userID": 555,"name":"xyz"}]    

var arr2 = [{"userID": 554,"lang":"ENG"},{"userID": 554,"lang":"GER"},{"userID": 555,"lang":"ENG"}]

var arr3 = [{"userID": 554,"SET":"QWE"},{"userID": 555,"SET":"ABC"},{"userID": 555,"SET":"XYZ"}]
```

Now I want to merge all these into one by the same key value i.e., userID, so my final output should be like

```
var final = [
    {
        "name":"abc"
        "userID": 554,
        "arr2" = [
            {
                "userID": 554,
                "lang":"ENG"
            },
            {
                "userID": 554,
                "lang":"GER"
            }
        ],
        "arr3" = [
            {
                "userID": 554,
                "SET":"QWE"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "userID": 555,
        "name":"xyz"
        "arr2" = [
            {
                "userID": 555,
                "name":"ENG"
            }
        ],
        "arr3" = [
            {
                "userID": 555,
                "SET":"ABC"
            },
            {
                "userID": 555,
                "SET":"XYZ"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I can't user ES6 with Spread operator (...) as I have a condition that it should be merged in the array where the key `userID` matches so that I gets the above output or like `{"userID": 554, "name": "abc", "lang": ["ENG", "GER"],...}`

Comment: If the question is **Can we?**, *Yes we can*.

Comment: You have a typo in the second array, name should be lang I suppose? else I think it is confusing...

Comment: @KungWaz Thanks, I have updated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [es6 using spread to concat multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455911/es6-using-spread-to-concat-multiple-arrays)

Comment: Why do you want to add arr2 and arr3 as props with arrays? Wouldn't it be more readable to have {"userID": 554, "name": "abc", "lang": ["ENG", "GER"],...}

Comment: You need to add the code ([mcve]) you've tried to solve this problem to your question. Asking us to solve it for you is against site guidelines when you've not shown that you've at least _tried_.

Comment: @KungWaz Yes, that could also do the job. I just need to merge them into one on the basis of same userID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one, should give exact output

```
let result = arr1.map(item =>{
    let obj = {};
    obj.userID = item.userID;
    obj.name = item.name;
    obj.arr2 = arr2.filter( it => it.userID === item.userID);
    obj.arr3 = arr3.filter( it => it.userID === item.userID);
    return obj;
})
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from @Deshak9

```js
var arr1 = [{"userID": 554,"name":"abc"},{"userID": 555,"name":"xyz"}]    
var arr2 = [{"userID": 554,"lang":"ENG"},{"userID": 554,"lang":"GER"},{"userID": 555,"lang":"ENG"}]
var arr3 = [{"userID": 554,"SET":"QWE"},{"userID": 555,"SET":"ABC"},{"userID": 555,"SET":"XYZ"}]

let result = arr1.map(item => {
    let obj = {};
    obj.userID = item.userID;
    obj.name = item.name;
    obj.lang = arr2.filter( it => it.userID === item.userID).map(item => { return item.lang; });
    obj.SET = arr3.filter( it => it.userID === item.userID).map(item => { return item.SET; });
    return obj;
})
console.log(result);
```

I think it makes it more readable to add all the values to an array for the given property. See the example below.

```
{
  "userID": 554,
  "name": "abc",
  "lang": [
    "ENG",
    "GER"
  ],
  "SET": [
    "QWE"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use

1. ES6 notation

   var arr1 = [{"userID": 554,"name":"abc"},{"userID": 555,"name":"xyz"}]

   var arr2 = [{"userID": 554,"lang":"ENG"},{"userID": 554,"lang":"GER"},{"userID": 555,"lang":"ENG"}]

   var arr3 = [{"userID": 554,"SET":"QWE"},{"userID": 555,"SET":"ABC"},{"userID": 555,"SET":"XYZ"}]

   const arr = [...arr1, ...arr2, ...arr3];
2. [Array.prototype.contact()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/concat)

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 it is pretty easy with Spread operator (...),

```js
var arr1 = [{"userID": 554,"name":"abc"},{"userID": 555,"name":"xyz"}]    

var arr2 = [{"userID": 554,"lang":"ENG"},{"userID": 554,"lang":"GER"},{"userID": 555,"lang":"ENG"}]

var arr3 = [{"userID": 554,"SET":"QWE"},{"userID": 555,"SET":"ABC"},{"userID": 555,"SET":"XYZ"}]

const merged = [].concat(...arr1,...arr2,...arr3)
console.log(merged)

//Another way of doing is,

const merged1 = [...arr1 , ...arr2,...arr3];
console.log(merged1)
```

Comment: When I run the snippet I get, {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'merged' has already been declared",

Comment: I need to merge it on the basis of same userID