# useState not updating an array correctly

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using React with Firebase to fetch data from firestore and display it to the user. Within a useEffect hook, I fetch the data and add it to an array of json objects. However, when adding a new element to the array, the previous one gets deleted. Below will be relevant portions of code.

```js
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const { currentUser } = useAuth();

function addItemToList(i) {
  const updatedList = [
    ...items,
    {
      data: i.data(),
      ref: i.ref
    }
  ]

  return updatedList;
} 
useEffect(() => {
  firestore.collection('items').where('uid', '==', currentUser.uid).get().then((itemSnapshot) => {
    itemSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      setItems(addItemToList(doc));
    })
  })
  setLoading(false);
}, []);
```

I've also tried updating the `items` list within the `useEffect` hook, but it produces the same bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me take a moment to explain what is happening here.

Your have to think in your react component as a "Snapshot", where a snapshot is the result of a render. Each snapshot points to a state created by useState and only to that one. What does this mean?

The first time your component renders (first snapshot) the items variable returned by useState is pointing to an empty array and as long as that snapshot is alive it would be pointing to that array.

So, lets take a look to the function called by useEffect

```
  firestore.collection('items').where('uid', '==', currentUser.uid).get().then((itemSnapshot) => {
    itemSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      setItems(addItemToList(doc));
    })
  })
  setLoading(false);
```

you are calling the set function for items once per elemtent in firebase query result and each call is seting a value that is the result of calling addItemToList

```
function addItemToList(i) {
  const updatedList = [
    ...items,
    {
      data: i.data(),
      ref: i.ref
    }
  ]

  return updatedList;
}
```

the point here is that you are always destructuring ...items which is always the items variable that the snapshot of the component is pointing to and it would not be updated until the component re rederds.

So, basically you all aways doing updatedList = [ ...[], { ... } ] becauses items has to wait to take update his value.

@Viet already responded with something good, which I think it's the best option

mapping the result of the query to an array and updating the array with the result of the map a parameter.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  firestore.collection('items').where('uid', '==', currentUser.uid).get().then((itemSnapshot) => {
    const result = [];
      itemSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        result.push({
          data: i.data(),
          ref: i.ref
        });
      })
    setItems(result);
  })
  setLoading(false);
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation; it was very insightful. Regarding @Viet 's solution, `itemQuerySnapshot` isn't itself an array. With that, do have any other suggestions?

Comment: Just added an quick fix for it, convert it to array and then update the state

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "addItemToList" to the dependencies of the useEffect hook.

Because you haven't done this, the effect references an old version of that function which references an old version of the items array.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but when I tried this solution, the useEffect hook would keep getting called, resulting in an infinite loop causing the app to crash.

Comment: Thats because the addItemsToList function would be a different one everytime. To fix this you need to wrap is in `useCallback` to make a consistent callback that doesnt change every render.

You can avoid all this however just by using the callback version of the setState function. `setItems(old => old.concat(newItems))`

Answer (score 0):

You just use `itemSnapshot.map` like this:

```
firestore.collection('items').where('uid', '==', currentUser.uid).get().then((itemSnapshot) => {
    setItems(
      itemSnapshot.map((doc) => ({
        data: i.data(),
        ref: i.ref,
      })),
    );
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The solution you suggested would not work since `itemSnapshot` is not an array. I tried rearranging my code to look more like your's (fixing issues ad needed), but I still run into the same issue.

Comment: `itemSnapshot` is not an array so why you can use `itemSnapshot.forEach`?

Comment: `itemSnapshot` is a method provided by firestore that allows you to iterate over all the documents fetched from the database. The data type, according to my editor, is `firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot<firebase.firestore.DocumentData>`

Comment: If `itemSnapshot` is not an array. You cannot use `forEach`

Comment: `forEach` is the specified way of getting all the documents fetched from the database, as per google's own documentation.

Comment: convert it to array

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running it for each value maybe you should try to map it as a list and update the state once

```
function addItemsToList(newItems) {
  const updatedList = [
    ...items,
    ...newItems
  ]

  return updatedList;
} 

useEffect(() => {
  firestore.collection('items').where('uid', '==', currentUser.uid).get().then((itemSnapshot) => {
    const docs = itemSnapshot.map((doc) => ({
       data: doc.data(),
       ref: doc.ref
    });
    setItems(addItemsToList(docs));
  })
  setLoading(false);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are using spread operator in a wrong way!** This way will not update the array.

You can do that by using **es6** spread to concat multiple arrays something like below:

```
const updatedList = [
    ...items,
    ...[{ data: i.data(), ref: i.ref }]
  ]
```

To know more: [Using es6 spread to concat multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455911/using-es6-spread-to-concat-multiple-arrays)